# javascript: windows.location not working at the first button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple HTML form where i have 2 buttons and 2 javascript code.
here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test(){

var addr=window.location.search;
alert(addr);

}

function validate(){
    var newaddr=window.location.search;
    alert(newaddr);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">

<input type="submit" id="input2" name="buttonupdate" value="update" onclick="test();"/>
<input type="submit" id="input1" name="buttosearch" value="search" onclick="validate();"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is, on click of 'update' button the alert should show the update button's name and value  and on click of search button search button's name and value should be shown by alert(). .
But what happens is on first time button click of update button the alert is blank then the address bar changes to

> `http://localhost:8080/button_test/check.html?buttonupdate=update`

later on if i click on update button it retrives the above url and shows proper value.
But if I click search button the same happen i.e the above url's value is retrived and address bar changes to

```
http://localhost:8080/button_test/check.html?buttosearch=search
```

how to achieve the desired result :( 
kindly guide  :(

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do??

Comment: i want to call respective functions on a particular button click and want to get the address of that button click only which the user clicks.

Comment: So based on your comment below, you'd like to get the current querystring, but also redirect? Makes no sense !

Comment: no i dont want to redirect..basically i am new to these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="submit" id="input2" name="buttonupdate" value="update" onclick="test(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: i want buttons only..no link :(

Answer (score 0):

it's best to bind an event to it, that you can pass the event as a target.

in HTML,

```
<input type="submit" id="input2" name="buttonupdate" value="update" />
<input type="submit" id="input1" name="buttosearch" value="search" />
```

in js,

```
function test(e){
    // obtain address ?
    var addr=window.location.search;
    // obtain value
    var value = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    // obtain name
    var name = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    // alert
    alert(name + " - " + value);
    // stop page load
    e.preventDefault();
}

function validate(e){
    var addr=window.location.search;
    var value = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    var name = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    alert(name + " - " + value);
    e.preventDefault();
}

// start
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //bind event to search
    var element = document.getElementById("input1");
    element.addEventListener('click', validate);
    // bind event to update
    var element = document.getElementById("input2");
    element.addEventListener('click', test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the  **variable search is null at first and it is updated after you submit**( that means after the call of your function),*you should understand this*!
But as a solution try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test(){

var addr=document.getElementById("input2").value;
addr+=" "+document.getElementById("input2").name;
alert(addr);

}

function validate(){
    var addr=document.getElementById("input1").value;
addr+=" "+document.getElementById("input1").name;
alert(addr);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">

<input type="submit" id="input2" name="buttonupdate" value="update" onclick="test();"/>
<input type="submit" id="input1" name="buttosearch" value="search" onclick="validate();"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `this` as parameter to your  functions :

```
<script>
function test(button){
    alert(button.name + " and " + button.value);
}

function validate(button){
   alert(button.name + " and " + button.value);
}
</script>
<input type="submit" id="input2" name="buttonupdate" value="update" onClick="test(this);"/>
<input type="submit" id="input1" name="buttosearch" value="search" onClick="validate(this);"/>
```

Comment: that's right 'this' is the object button and you can use all the properties defined for this object.